# How to sum() positive/negative numbers in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, sum, value-of

To sum a series of values (positive or negative) use the sum() function in XPath.

In this example, we get transactions from an XML source and puts it into a variable. Then we sum it up in the end.

XML Source:

```
<month month="04">
 <balance in="987000,00" acnt="1100"/>
 <balance in="167440,00" acnt="1280"/>
 <balance in="1098000,00" acnt="1380"/>
 <balance in="575000,00" acnt="1460"/>
 <balance in="-75000,00" acnt="1469"/>
 ...
</month>
```

XSLT:

This results in the following structure:

```
<account>
 <month month="name">
  <in>987000.00</in>
 </month>
 ...
</account>
```

To sum the values we use the following XSLT snippet:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(ext:node-set($sumSet)//in)"/>
```

This example was run in Visual Studio.

Comment: Works as expected for me. [Demo here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/6D4ZIX). What result were you expecting?

Comment: What system are you using. When I try that on saxon (well, exslt:node-set) I get the right answer (2094173)

Comment: My bad - I had a couple of other ingredients that failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was a bit off so I edited the whole thing and provided the answer. :)